# React native router flux: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'addListener')

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-thunk, react-native-router-flux

Im working on a react native app using this principal dependencies:

- react native
- react native router flux
- react thunk
- expo

I was working using this package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "23.0.4",
    "humps": "^2.0.0",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "native-base": "^2.3.5",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.4",
    "react-native-extend-indicator": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^4.13.0",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.6",
    "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.0-beta.24",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation-redux-debouncer": "^0.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "swagger-client": "2.1.32"
  }
```

The application is using expo so i install the dependencies using:

- yarn install

and then run the app by

- yarn start --reset-cache

I was working fine since i wanted to add a new dependencie, so i remove the node_modules folder and the yarn.lock file, added the new dependencie and execute yarn install again.

After that, im getting this error when opening the application:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'addListener')

[image]

it is related with react-navigation, but im using react-native-router-flux 4.0.0-beta.24 that uses react-navigation ^1.0.0-beta.19 internally.

I have recently notice that people using react-navigation are having some troubbles with this (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3416) but using the beta.28 version.

If i go back to a previous node_modules folder (from the trash) my application runs well, so.. probably the thing is that some dependency with the *^* symbol of my package.json is no more compatible.. maybe thunk or react native router flux with my react native version.

any ideas?

Here is the part of the code when i use the react thunk middleware:

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import getRootReducer from "../reducers/index";
import navigationDebouncer from 'react-navigation-redux-debouncer';
import {restApi} from "../lib/restApi";

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({ predicate: (getState, action) => __DEV__  });

export default function getStore(initialState) {
    const enhancer = compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware.withExtraArgument(restApi),
            navigationDebouncer(600),
            loggerMiddleware
        ),
    );
    return createStore(
        getRootReducer,
        initialState,
        enhancer
    );
}
```

and here is the main app:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import getStore from './src/store/configureStore'
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native'
import AppNavigation from './src/navigation';

const Store = getStore();

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
            'Ionicons': require('native-base/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
        });
    }

    render() {
        StatusBar.setHidden(true);
        return (
            <Provider store={Store}>
                <AppNavigation/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT: i have found that now react-native-router-flux uses 1.0.0 react-navigation (the new stable release), and after it was using the 1.0.0-beta.27 version.. the application works with the beta version but has this problem with the 1.0.0 version...**
so i realice that you are using a fixed version of react navigation in your last release (1.0.0-22.beta)

so the question is, is there a way to still using RNRF 4.0.0-beta.24 BUT using a fixed version (like 1.0.0-27.beta for example) ?

i mean, i think that is make no sence that 4.0.0-beta.24 uses ^1.0.0-beta19 (that will result in the installation of the last 1.0.0 release) and a newer version like 4.0.0-beta.28 uses a fixed lower version (1.0.0-beta.22)

Answer (score 8):

So after doing some research and some tests i want to answer my question.

The problem was with the **react-navigation** dependency that handles internally **react-native-router-flux**

The dependencies are:

```
react-native-router-flux beta.0 - beta.24 -> react-navigation ^1.0.0-beta.19
react-native-router-flux beta.25 - beta.28 -> react-navigation 1.0.0-beta.22
```

the big difference here is that versions from 0 to beta24 uses **^**

**So .. what is the problem with that?**

when installing the dependencies beta24 will search for the newest version of react-navigation since 1.0.0-beta.19, that version is the recent stable release 1.0.0 of react-navigation (the library is no more in beta version).

**react-native-router-flux doesnt provide support for that dependency**. It doesnt provide support to other olders dependencies neither, so they had just put the **1.0.0-beta22** **react-navigation dependency** fixed on their lastest releases package.json (since beta 26).

probably they will fix it since there are a lot of apps that use redux or other libraries that doesnt have good interaction with react-native-router-flux.

So for now.. the **solution** for Redux users is to go for the beta26 version, and for people that doesnt use redux probably beta27 and beta28 will be ok.

Here is the discussion: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2865

Here is another related issue: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2799

Comment: You are my hero