# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating userItems.map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, map-function

Edit: Now i'm using "react-native-navigation@latest" everything is fine.

When i open the app **first time** **it is fething data properly** but after **second refresh**  error occured

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'userItems.map')
>
> this error is located at:
>   in Users (created by Connect(Users));
>   ....
>
> ....

Component/Users.js

```
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const userItems = this.props.users || [];
    const abc = userItems.map((user,index) => (
      <Text key={index}>
      {user.email}
      </Text>
    ));
    return (
      <View>
        {abc}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  users: state.UserReducer.items
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchUsers
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

Actions

```
export function fetchUsers() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch("http://example.com/v1/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users =>
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USERS,
          payload: users
        })
      );
  };
}
```

reducer/userReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_USERS } from "../Actions/types";

    const initialState = {
      items: []
    };

    const userReducer= (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
            case FETCH_USERS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    items:action.payload
                }
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
export default userReducer;
```

reducer/index.js

```
import UserReducer from './userReducer';
const AppReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  UserReducer,
  ...
  ...
  ...
});

export default AppReducer;
```

*backend is fine i testes with postman*

users backend

```
  const router = new express.Router();

  router.route("/users").get((req, res) => {
    User.find({},{password:0}, (err, users) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(404).send({message: "error"});
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        return res.status(200).send({users});
      }
    });
  });
```

response backend

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "dateCreated": "..",
            "dateModified": "...",
            "lastLogin": "...",
            "_id": "...",
            "email": "...",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "dateCreated": "..",
            "dateModified": "...",
            "lastLogin": "...",
            "_id": "...",
            "email": "...",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

package.json dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "asyncstorage": "^1.5.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "v1.0.0-beta.26",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

Comment: Most likely `users` from your api response isn't array

Comment: it is array i am pretty sure because i did fetch before i am now implementing it my new project but not working

Comment: are you using react-navigation in your code [as a dependency]?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're mapping your action inside your MapDispatchToProps? (Ideally this post would be a comment but I do not have comment permissions yet).

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers());
    };    
};
```

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps` can be an object too! [source](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Answer (score 0):

If `/users` response is this :

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "dateCreated": "..",
            "dateModified": "...",
            "lastLogin": "...",
            "_id": "...",
            "email": "...",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Then when dispatching `FETCH_USERS`, you should do it like this : (notice the payload property)

```
export function fetchUsers() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch("http://example.com/v1/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data =>
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USERS,
          payload: data.users
        })
      );
  };
}
```

Or you can do this inside the reducer (notice the items property) :

```
const userReducer= (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_USERS:
             return {
                  ...state,
                  items: action.payload.users 
             }
             default:
             return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it did properly load data first but when i changed page or refresh the page error occured again.

Comment: This may be related to where you are calling `this.props.fetchUsers();`, try calling it inside `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is using the react-native-router-flux (which has react-navigation as a dependency), from the code sample given. There is an open issue with this [listed on github](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2865). The current solution to this, as discussed in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48676614/1675954) is to use the beta26 version + of react-native router-flux. 
I suspect this will solve your problem. If not, well, worth a shot! ..

Hth..

Comment: i am using     "react-navigation": "v1.0.0-beta.26",

Comment: Make sure you have the correct peer dependencies installation. Are you using yarn or npm? I got this error once for something else and upgrading all my dependencies, and updating the version of npm worked to correct the error

Comment: I tried to delete node modules and install again with yarn and npm both times same error. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: I didn't delete the node modules manually. I just upgraded to the latest vsn of npm, installed latest vsn of yarn. And then used yarn to upgrade each dependency. I think I removed the dependencies from the project, upgraded them globally and added them back in.

Comment: Compare the dependencies you're using with those listed in your package.json and your android file listed dependencies also. Remove any unnecessary. I found that useful..

Comment: @RacheIGallen changed my navigation library to "react-native-navigation@latest" everything is fine now. And it is native, work like a charm.

Comment: @BatuhanSahan could you accept my answer (by hovering beside answer and clicking on the checkmark), to mark this as solved? Thanks.